# What parts of linguistics deal with the differences between text types?

Tags: theoretical-linguistics, linguistic-universals, forensic-linguistics, text-classification

There are different types of texts, for I stance:

- manuals
- short stories
- novels
- recipes
- love letters
- testaments
- contracts
- fines
- books for teaching children to read
- political speeches
- motivational speeches, like Jean Claude van damme talking to th UN soldiers in Street fighter - the movie
- police reports

  and so forth

Is there a field of linguistics which deals with analyzing them and establishing grammatical characteristics for each type of text. 
Maybe, after a statistical evaluation of text types and comparison with each other one could come up with stable or frequent characteristics for each text type, perhaps differences like:

- the number of different words used per thousand words
- the average length or structural complexity of a sentence
- different spectrograms of the types of phrases used

I understand the field or fields have to be quiet extensive, therefore I don't ask for a description, but rather a list of the names of the  linguistic subfields, theories and significant people dealing with it, maybe with  short annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The features mentioned in the last paragraph of the question belong to the domain of [corpus linguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpus_linguistics) and [stylometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylometry).

For the categories mentioned in the first part of the question, [Systemic Functional Linguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemic_functional_linguistics) offers a lot of categories for analysis, like *register*, *tenor*, *field*, or *mode*. Maybe you want to learn more about this by studying the works of M.A.K. Halliday and R. Hasan.

Comment: I think, stylometry is here the centre of the bullseye....As for systemic functional linguistics, I read the article and either my brain is to weak to comprehend or it borders to esoterics...I fear it is the first

Comment: If I got it right, stylometry is about examining styles by means of statistics, it is applicable to comparing authors, genres, classifying texts into the epoche of their creation and for Sherlock Holmes fans even to determine whether the death thread was written by woody Allen, Quentin Tarantino, Erdogan or a Chimpanzee in one of those animal type writer experiments